# For-loop based on idex in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have this data.frame `A`

```
A 
Index  col2
1      10
2      7
3      3
```

and this data.frame `B`

```
index  col2   col3 
    1      0.2    0.8
    2      0.3    0.7
    3      0.1    0.9
```

Now I would calculate the percentage proportion of `df(A[,2])`, with the value in col1 and col2 of `df(B)` when the index is the same. 
The expected output is :

```
C
col1   col2
0.002  0.008  # A[1,2]/100*B[1,2]=0.002 & A[1,2]/100*B[1,3]=0.008 if the index is the same for the two data.frame, in this case is 1
.... ....
0.003  0.0027 #A[3,2]/100*B[3,2] & [3,2]/100*B[3,3] because the index is the same, 3 in this case.
```

How can do it with (only) `loop for` please?

Comment: You got a downvote from me for insisting on solutions with a `for` loop without giving a (compelling) reason.

Comment: if i use a loop-for i can manage directly every input, and for example i can use a MOTE CARLO simulation write by my self...

Comment: Doing this with a `for` loop instead of vectorized operations is slow. For an MC simulation you need fast code.

Comment: Do you know wihout for-loop, i can use sapply? (The underlying answers don't include the operation based on index)

Comment: `sapply` is not more efficient than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
A[,2][row(B[-1])]/100*B[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try nesting for loops:

```
A <- read.table(text = "
                   Index col2
                   1       10
                   2       7
                   3       3
", header = TRUE)

B <- read.table(text = "
                col2 col3
                0.2       0.8
                0.3       0.7
                0.1       0.9
                ", header = TRUE)

for(i in 1:3){
  for(f in 1:2){
print(A[i,f]/100*B[i,f])
  }
}
```

i represents the number of rows (so if this is only a small example change `1:3` to `1:nrows(data)`) and f represents the number of columns (so if this is only a small example change `1:2` to `1:ncol(data)`)

Answer (score 0):

The data

```
df_a <- data.frame(index = c(1, 2, 3), col2 = c(10, 7, 3))
df_b <- data.frame(index = c(1, 2, 3), col2 = c(.2, .3, .1), col3 = c(.8, .7, .9))
```

Without loop:

```
(df_a[, 2] / 100) * df_b[, 2:3]
```

With loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df_a)) print((df_a[i, 2] / 100) * (df_b[i, 2:3]))
```